# Laravel Blade: Something similar to Jinja2 block

Tags: php, laravel, jinja2, laravel-blade

Is there an existing way in Blade to mimic Jinja2's `block` construct?

I understand it is possible to use `@yield('content', '<h1>Default content</h1>')`, but this is clunky and ugly if you want the default content to be much bigger than a small string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `@section/@show` instead of `@yield`:

```
@section('content')
default content
@show
```

and override as usual:

```
@section('content')
override
@stop
```

Comment: So you would used the `default` in the template and the `override` in the actual view?